# Replacing passwords in /etc/shadow with masking text for administrative purposes

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Given that the shadow file has been copied to a different location

```
sudo cp /etc/shadow ~
```

To check if the user has a password, we can just `cat` it. However, to not alarm people with the act of copying their `/etc/shadows`, I will need to mask the password hash. This will definitely require regex.......

```
john:$6$iTEFbMTM$CXmxPwErbEef9RUBvf1zv8EgXQdaZg2eOd5uXyvt4sFzi6G4lIqavLilTQgniAHm3Czw/LoaGzoFzaMm.YwOl/:17707:0:90:14:::
jane:*:99999:0:90:14:::
```

Is anyone able to help me with the regex required to replace the password hash for either sed or awk command?

Edit: Forgot to add that those with `*` as the password field should not be replaced (since they are not passwords anyway).

```
sed -i 's/REGEX/MASKINGTEXT/g' ~/shadow
```

Expected outcome:

```
john:MASKINGTEXT:17707:0:90:14:::
jane:*:99999:0:90:14:::
```

Comment: Could you please add sample output in your post and let us know then?

Comment: Why not use simple command `passwd -a -S | awk '{ if ($2="P") print $1}'` to get accounts with a password or `passwd -a -S | awk '{ if ($2="NP") print $1}'` for accounts without a password?

Comment: You are playing with fire operating on `/etc/shadow` with `sed -i`. Unix `passwd` is the proper way to replace a password hash.

Comment: Which is why the first line says that the file has been copied to a different location

Answer (score 2):

If it is always 2nd field, then why not keep it simple by changing only 2nd field itself by `awk`.

```
sudo awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$2="your_new_value_here"} 1' Input_file
```

2nd warning: As per @David sir's comment too: Please DO NOT use in-place EDIT, you could print the output on terminal and then could use proper tool to edit/create new /etc/shadow file.

1st warning: 
Run above command first and if you are happy with results then you could save output into Input_file itself. In case you have gawk with latest version you could use `gawk -i inplace` for above code too, to save output into Input_file itself.

Comment: Yep, I UV'ed the answer, that was more a double-warning for the OP in case he really wants to do that. One slip of a key and POOF. (it's reboot, edit the grub command line and add `init=/bin/bash` just to be able to hack your way back into a system with no passwords)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, Thank you sir, I have added additional comment in my answer, request you please take a look and feel free to let me know in case any problems sir.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, Thank you sir for encouragement.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sudo cat /etc/shadow | sed -E 's/^([^:]+:)([^:]+)(..+)$/\1redacted\3/g'
```

Edit (unnecessary `cat` command):

```
sudo sed -E 's/^([^:]+:)([^:]+)(..+)$/\1redacted\3/g' /etc/shadow
```

Comment: Note that `sed` doesn't have look-ahead/behind, we need to capture the entire line with 3 groups (\1,\2,\3) and replace the second group with the text you want to replace.

Comment: Why not `sudo sed -E '....' /etc/shadow` rather than unnecessarily piping after a cat. (*UUOc* - Unnecessary Use Of `cat`)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Thank you